# Virtual Network using Vmware

Tags: python, sockets, vmware

I have a vmware workstation pro 12 and I can open multiple virtual machines at a time. All wanted is to connect them in a virtual network. This will allow me to create a server(using python sockets) in a virtual machines and other VMs act as clients. Is my idea possible? if possible How can I do it.

Comment: Are you asking how to generate multiple virtual machines and configure them on the same network? That's not a programming question.

Comment: This question has some problems, so some hints for the OP: (1) Stack Overflow is not a place where others will write code for you, but rather a place where others can help out if you encounter a specific coding problem and you upload a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Furthermore, (2) the question seems to resemble a _best practice_ question, [which are mostly considered to be a bad habbit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353) on SO. Finally (3) I doubt whether what the OP is asking is a programming question at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if this help but your question doesnt really help either.

So the last time I used vmware was for virtual machine. I think it was called wmware workstation 12. I used the free version which lets you use it for noncommercial use. If you are using that then this most likely applies.

So because its not the pro or commercial version you can only open one virtual machine at a time. But from your question seems like your using python. Not sure what that means. But what i am trying to say is if its the free version then you may only be able to open one virtual machine at a time.

This maybe the problem your having.

I hoped this helps, if not you then someone else.

**EDIT**

Here is a few youtube video i have found that will help to make a virtual network. You need to make a host-only network. May wish to turn on dhcp. Once your created the virtual network. All the vms need to use the same virtual network. Now that your vms are on the same network and are able to communicate with each other hopefully your python script should work. Im not sure how to use pyhton. Otherwise would have provided code to open a simple socket and test it from client side. Anyway im sure you could your script correctly and it should work now. You may need to use ipconfig (windows cmd)/ifconfig (unix terminal) to find the ip address of the server machine.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VPkRC0mKF4

https://youtu.be/vKoFSmy3agM?t=131

Here is link to simple python server

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm

the host variable in the client code should be the ip of the server and not gethostname. so use ifconfig/ipconfig on server to find the server ip.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will try it out very soon